# Each permutation in $A_k$ can be written as a product of $3$-cycles of the form $(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4),...,(1 ,2,k)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Each permutation in $A_k$ can be written as a product of $3$-cycles of the form $(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4),...,(1, 2, k)$.
I am trying to start this problem by induction but I am having trouble with the base case...
I tried for $k=3$,
$(123)=(123)^3$,
$(312)=(123)^5$,
$(321)=(123)(123)$,
$(231)=(123)$,
but I can't figure out $(213)$ and $(132)$.

Comment: The base case is when $k =3$, in which case $A_3$ has only three elements, and this can be trivially brute forced....

Comment: I tried by saying (123) =(123), (312)=(123)(123) but I couldn't get (321) for example... I added this to my question...

Comment: (312)=(123)(123) is wrong. Also, (312) = (123).

Comment: The usual notation is that $(123)=(312)$ and that $(321)=(123)(123)$.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting this notation... Doesn't one start from the right and read left. So in (123)(123), 1->2->3 then 3->2->1; 2->3->1 then 1->2->3 and then 3->1->2 then 2->3->1 so I get (312).... Also like (12)(13)=(312)...

Comment: T. Bongers I see why (312)=(123) now... I don't understand how I would get what (123)(123) is...

Comment: I found a video that helped me. Thanks so much everyone.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8HaZsAbgeQ I am thankful for your help :) You helped me realize I was doing this wrong.